# shoulda should "be valid" do fails with "'handle_matcher': undefined method 'matches?'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, shoulda

I'm trying out 'shoulda' on top of rspec (rails 3) with the following spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Article do
  should "be true" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

and it fails with

```
/Users/jeppe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rspec-expectations-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:11:in `handle_matcher': undefined method `matches?' for "be true":String (NoMethodError)
```

Now my tests will run just fine when I do both

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Article do
  it "should be true" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

and

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Article do
  it { should belong_to :issue }
  it { should have_and_belong_to_many :pages }
  it { should have_many :tasks }
end
```

where the last uses Shoulda::ActiveRecord::Matchers, so to my knowledge shoulda is loaded allright.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RSpec `should` is an RSpec method used to trigger a matcher - it is not Shouldas context block. For that, you use RSpecs own `describe`.

```
should "be true" do
  assert true
end
```

is Shoulda's Test::Unit based syntax, which shouldn't work in RSpec examples (I guess?). Just use your second example, which has the same effect and the right syntax.

Comment: Ok, so I was 'just' confused with Test::Unit vs Rspec syntax - thanks for pointing that out :-)